# Why buttons added to my navigationitem looks like inactive?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uinavigationitem

I have an iPad app with splitViewController. In my RootViewController
i add buttons to edit list of items and to add a new item

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 500.0);

    //  Configure the Edit button
    [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:[self editButtonItem]];

    //  Configure the Add button
    UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(add)];



    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:addButton];
    [addButton release];

}
```

it work fine. Buttons taps. Call selectors. But buttons looks like they is inactive (grayed). Title is also gray. Why?

What i need to do to give them a standard layout?

Comment: which button? the edit button? or the add button?

Comment: both edit and add and a title too.

Comment: can you take a screenshot and attach it to your post, i don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Here is link to screenshot http://pics.livejournal.com/torgvi/pic/000cd6kr i cant attach it to post becouse i havent enough reputation points, sorry.

Comment: That is actually the correct and default colour for the iPad Split View Controller

Comment: Thanx for explanation. I think that it must be similar like an iphone apps.

Answer (score 0):

may be this is for this line.Comment this line

self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

Answer (score 0):

From your screen shot the colours of the BarButtonItems are the correct and default colours of the UISplitViewController.

if you would like to customize the colour of the BarButtonItems you can do so by providing a tintColor which will modify the colour the button.

```
addButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```